Linear dependency between functions and their span
Given functions:
$$
f(x) = (m-14)e^{3x}+(m-5)e^x+3e^{-x}, \quad 
g(x) = 5e^{3x}-2me^x+me^{-x}
$$
Assignment:
Find all $m$ values (if there are any) where:
$$\dim(\operatorname{span}\{f,g\}) = 2,\ \dim(\operatorname{span}\{f,g\}) = 1, \ \dim(\operatorname{span}\{f,g\}) = 0.$$
Question:
I am not yet familiar with functions as vectors, so I find it hard to understand what represents what.
What I understand:
$e^{3x}, e^x, e^{-x}$ are my vectors, and their coefficients represent the scalars.
What I don't understand:
When I plug those functions into a span function, do I need to multiply them again by scalars to show the span of those functions? For example:
$$
\operatorname{span}\{f,g\} = \alpha f(x) + \beta g(x)
$$
or are the coefficients enough?
I believe that when $\dim(\operatorname{span}\{f,g\}) = 2$ (if it is possible), the vectors $f$ and $g$ should be linearly independent. This means we cannot express $f$ as a scalar multiple of $g$ (i.e., $f = k \cdot g$). Alternatively, it means:
$$
\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) = 0
$$
has only one solution: $\alpha = 0, \beta = 0$.
For $\dim(\operatorname{span}\{f,g\}) = 1$, the vectors $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent. This means there are infinitely many solutions to the system of equations.
For $\dim(\operatorname{span}\{f,g\}) = 0$, this means that the span contains only the zero vector ($\mathbf{0}$). Does this imply that $f$ and $g$ must both be zero, i.e., all coefficients must vanish?
Request for clarification:
I have outlined my understanding and approach to solving this question. If there are errors or misconceptions, I would greatly appreciate corrections to help me improve my grasp of this topic.

(Attempted) Solution:
If I am correct up to this point, my approach would be:
let the span be:
$ \alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) = \alpha ((m-14)e^{3x}+(m-5)e^x+3e^{-x}) + \beta (5e^{3x}-2me^x +me^{-x}) = ((m-14)\alpha + 5\beta)e^{3x} + ((m-5)\alpha -2m\beta)e^{x} + (3\alpha + m\beta)e^{-x}$
Checking linear dependency:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
(m-14)\alpha + 5\beta = 0 \\
(m-5)\alpha -2m\beta = 0 \\
3\alpha + m\beta = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
m-14 & 5 & 0 \\
m-5  & -2m & 0 \\
3    & m   & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
Now, we solve for values of $m$ and search: when there is one solution, meaning that for those values, $f,g$ are linearly independent, and when there are infinite solutions, meaning, they are linearly dependent.
After that, we would try to see if we can get all coefficients to be zero meaning $f(x),g(x) = 0$ meaning that the only vector in the span is the zero vector.
